# Springboot findBy List<String> Hibernate @Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, web-services

I have entity shown below:

```
@Entity
public class Specialist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    String accountId;
    @NotNull(message = "Province may not be blank")
    Province province;
    @NotBlank(message = "City may not be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 25, message = "City must be between 2 and 32 characters")
    String city;
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "profession", nullable = false)
    List<String> professions;
}
```

and in Repository i want to create method which find specialists by province,city and profession with following rules:

- if province,city and professions is empty then return all of specialists
- if only province is empty return specialists by city and professions
- if only city is empty return specialists by province and professions
- if only professions is empty return specialists by province and city
- if province and professions is empty return specialists by city
- if city and professions is empty return specialists by province
- if province and city is empty return specialists by professions

and next aspect which needed to pay attention is that professions may have several items for example plumber and automatic or mechanic,designer,electrician.

and my question is how to iterate over all the things in the list to find specific specialists.

For example if I create in postman 3 specialists with following professions:

1. professions:["plumber","automatic","designer"]
2. professions:["designer"]
3. professions:["plumber","electrician"]

and as a parameter in query params use ?professions=electrician,automatic then i will receive 1,3 specialists
if ?professions=designer then i will receive 1,2 specialists
if ?professions=gardener then i will receive empty list of specialists

I've implemented in Repository following method:

```
    /*Find SPECIALIST by location and profession*/
        @Query("SELECT c FROM Specialist c WHERE (:province is null or c.province = :province)  and (:city is null or c.city = :city) and (:professions is null or c.professions in (:professions))")
    HashSet<Specialist> findSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfession(@Param("province")Province province, @Param("city")String city, @Param("professions") List<String> professions);
```

in serviceImpl:

```
 @Override
    public HashSet<Specialist> findSpecialists(Province province, String city, List<String> profession){
        if(specialistRepo.count() == 0) throw new SpecialistNotFoundException("Any Specialist isn't exist");
        return specialistRepo.findSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfession(province,city,profession);
    }
```

and in controller:

```
@GetMapping("/get")
    public HashSet<Specialist> getSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfession(@RequestParam(value = "province",required = false) Province province,
                                                                            @RequestParam(value = "city",required = false)String city,
                                                                            @RequestParam(value = "profession", required = false) List<String> profession){
        return specialistService.findSpecialists(province,city,profession);
    }
```

if i used GET method in postman then i've received this error:

```
 "message": "Parameter value [mechanik] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [mechanik] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [mechanik] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [mechanik] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.findSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfession(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat pl.specialist.searchexpert.services.SpecialistServiceImpl.findSpecialists(SpecialistServiceImpl.java:88)\r\n\tat pl.specialist.searchexpert.controllers.SpecialistController.getSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfession(SpecialistController.java:89)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [mechanik] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.expandListValuedParameters(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:636)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\r\n\t... 63 more\r\n",
```

I made a query through "curl" but I suppose that this is this same response 
EDIT 2:

```
Microsoft Windows [Wersja 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone.

\Windows\system32>curl http://localhost:8080/api/specialist/get?professions=me
chanic
{"timestamp":"2020/04/17 17:03:36","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error",
"message":"could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hiber
nate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet","trace":"org.sp
ringframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract Res
ultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarExcepti
on: could not extract ResultSet
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)\r\n
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
 org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
 org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
 org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
 org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.findSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfessionsIn(Unknown Source) pl.specialist.searchexpert.services.specialist.SpecialistServiceImpl.findSpecialists(SpecialistServiceImpl.java:86) pl.specialist.searchexpert.controllers.SpecialistController.getSpecialistsByProvinceAndCityAndProfession(SpecialistController.java:88)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilte
rChain.java:193) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilte
r(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
 org.
springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
 org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
 org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) 
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
 org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
 org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
 org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
 org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562)
org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)tat org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618)\rorg.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
 org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
 org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\r\n\t... 63 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 5
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
 om.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)... 92 more\r\n",
"path":"/api/specialist/get","version":"0.1"}
C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: anybody have got way to solve this ?